# Uninstall ubuntu issue

Tags: partitioning, uninstall, windows-10, disk-management, secure-erase

I have been trying to remove ubuntu. But I can't. I installed Ubuntu on hdd(drive) and has windows in c. I tried to delete the ubuntu volume using disk management on windows but the delete volume options doesn't pops out. Only help option is available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are always issues with trying to reconfigure the disk you're currently booted off of.

it might be worthwhile trying a tool like [Gparted](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) that will boot of of USB and allow modification of the internal drives.